# Per-element array operation on multidimensional matrix

Tags: javascript, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array

I'm creating a 2D matrix in javascript, where each element in that matrix is an empty array.

The problem is, whenever I try to push to one of the elements in the matrix, the push gets applied to the entire matrix, not the specific element.

Here is the code:

```
function createMatrix(numrows, numcols, initialValue = []) {
   var matrix = []; var row = [];
   while (numcols--) row[row.length] = initialValue;
   while (numrows--) matrix[matrix.length] = row.slice();
   return matrix;
};

function printMatrix(matrix) {
   var output = '';
   for (var i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
       output += '[';
       for (var j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
           output += '  ' + matrix[i][j];
       }
       output += '  ]\n';
   }
   console.log(output);
};

// Example code
var A = createMatrix(3,6, []);
printMatrix(A)

// This is the output:
// [              ]
// [              ]
// [              ]

// For example, we now try to add number 7 to the empty array at [1][2]
A[1][2].unshift(7);

// Let's see how the matrix looks like:
printMatrix(A)
// [  7  7  7  7  7  7  ]
// [  7  7  7  7  7  7  ]
// [  7  7  7  7  7  7  ]
```

The above matrix is wrong. Instead of the push being applied to only a single element, it gets applied to the entire matrix. In other words, the correct output should look like this:

```
// [                    ]
// [        7           ]
// [                    ]
```

Your help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use slice for the rows elements for getting a independent elements.

```
while (numrows--) matrix[matrix.length] = row.map(a => a.slice());
//                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

```js
function createMatrix(numrows, numcols, initialValue = []) {
   var matrix = []; var row = [];
   while (numcols--) row[row.length] = initialValue;
   while (numrows--) matrix[matrix.length] = row.map(a => a.slice());
   return matrix;
};

function printMatrix(matrix) {
   var output = '';
   for (var i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
       output += '[';
       for (var j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
           output += '  ' + matrix[i][j];
       }
       output += '  ]\n';
   }
   console.log(output);
};

// Example code
var A = createMatrix(3,6, []);
printMatrix(A)

// This is the output:
// [              ]
// [              ]
// [              ]

// For example, we now try to add number 7 to the empty array at [1][2]
A[1][2].unshift(7);

// Let's see how the matrix looks like:
printMatrix(A)
```

Answer (score 0):

***The first problem*** is that you're trying to assign the reference of the same initial array `initialValue` to each column with the line:

```
while (numcols--) row[row.length] = initialValue;  // <----
```

That's why all the columns were filled with same value.
The solution for the first problem is:

```
while (numcols--) row[row.length] = initialValue.slice();
```

---

***The second problem***: *If your array contains nested arrays, the "clone" will contain references to the old arrays.* 
This is the case which happens on your matrix rows on this line:

```
while (numrows--) matrix[matrix.length] = row.slice();  // <---
```

The solution for the second problem would be cloning all nested arrays using `Array.protottype.map()` function:

```
while (numrows--) matrix[matrix.length] = row.map(function(arr){ return arr.slice(); });
```

---

Now, you'll get the needed output:

```
A[1][2].unshift(7);

[              ]
[      7        ]
[              ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comments and answers everyone. Much appreciated.

I also came to the same conclusion that the problem was due to a shallow copy because of 'slice()'. Here is a simpler implementation that solves the problem, in case anybody needs it in the future:

```
function createMatrix(dimensions) {
    var matrix = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < dimensions[0]; ++i)
      matrix[matrix.length] = (dimensions.length == 1 ? [] : createMatrix(dimensions.slice(1)));

    return matrix;
};
```